# UrlRewrite filter with tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, url-rewriting

I am using org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter on my java project.It works fine .My issue is it change the existing url.

example i need to redirect mainurl/news/cricket to mainurl/news.jsp/id=2

## myurlrewriter.xml

```
<rule>
    <note>
        The rule means that requests to /test/status/ will be redirected to /rewrite-status
        the url will be rewritten.
    </note>
    <from>/news/cricket</from>
    <to type="redirect">%{context-path}/news.jsp/id=2</to>
</rule>
```

It redirect the entire url to news.jsp/id=2 but i dont want to change the url ,only change the contents, is it possible?anybody knows how do it.

Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
VKS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then don't use a redirect. It will send a 302, which means it's telling the browser that the page has moved. Just lose the `type="redirect"`:

```
<rule>
    <note>
        The rule means that requests to /test/status/ will be redirected to /rewrite-status
        the url will be rewritten.
    </note>
    <from>/news/cricket</from>
    <to>/news.jsp/id=2</to>
</rule>
```